# Determine the first three non-zero terms in the Taylor polynomial approximation for the initial value problem: $y''+\sin(y)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, taylor-expansion

Having trouble understanding how to solve this problem.  Did I at least set it up correctly?

$y''+\sin(y)=0,\;y(0)=1,\;y'(0)=0$

So assuming $y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$ then $y''(x)=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}$

And since $\sin(y)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}$ rewriting the original equation I get:

$$y''+\sin(y) = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

I tried combining terms and simplifying so that I can solve for $a_{n+2}:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n\left((n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}+\frac{(-1)^nx^2}{(2n!)}\right)$$

But I don't know how to get rid of the factor of $x$ inside the parenthesis so that I can solve for the coefficient.  Am I going down the wrong path?

Comment: you have the Taylor series of cos x and not sin y.

Comment: @DougM yes, I just noticed that.  Is fixing it just a matter of swapping the variables?  I don't know how I could then combine and solve the equation if that is the case...

Comment: If you only need the first 3 terms of the series.  So, sin y = y should suffice.  if you need the 4th term then sin y = y - y^3/6.  But then, y = a_0 + a_1x + a_2 x^2... and you will need to cube that.

Comment: @DougM sorry I don't really understand what you're saying.  Why should $\sin(y)=y)$ suffice?

Comment: It is not sufficient, since the solution is symmetric, $y(-x)=y(x)$. Thus the first three non-zero terms are the constant, quadratic and fourth degree terms.

Comment: @free_mind I will give a detailed answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are going about this the wrong way!

You have $y(0)=1$

You have $y'(0)=0$

Since $y''+\sin(y)=0$, you have $y''(0)+\sin(y(0))=0 \Rightarrow y''(0)+\sin(1)=0 \Rightarrow y''(0)= - \sin(1)$

Next differentiate $y''+\sin(y)=0$ with respect to $x$

You get $y'''+\cos(y) y'=0$ (Chain Rule)

$y'''(0)+\cos(y(0)) y'(0)=0 \Rightarrow y'''(0)+\cos(1) \times 0=0 \Rightarrow  y'''(0)=0$

Differentiate $y'''+\cos(y) y'=0$ with respect to $x$

You get $y''''-\sin(y) (y')^2+\cos(y) y''=0$ (Product Rule)

$y''''(0)-\sin(y(0)) (y'(0))^2+\cos(y(0)) y''(0)=0$

$\Rightarrow y''''(0)-\cos(1) \sin(1)=0 \Rightarrow y''''(0)=\cos(1) \sin(1)$

The series is given by $y(0)+y'(0)x+\frac 12y''(0)x^2+\frac 1{3!}y'''(0)x^3+\frac 1{4!}y''''(0)x^4+\frac 1{5!}y'''''(0)x^5+...$

Substituting the first three non-zero values gives:

$1-\frac 12 \sin(1)x^2+\frac 1{4!}\sin(1)\cos(1)x^4$

Answer (score 3):

$y = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3$

$y(0) = 1, y'(0) = 0$

$y = 1 + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3$

$y'' = 2 a_2 + 6 a_3 x + 12 a_4 x^2$

$\sin y = y - y^3 / 6 + y^5/5!...$

$y^3 = 1 + 3 a_2 x^2 + 3 a_3 x^3 + 3 a_2x^4 + 3a_4 x^4...$

$y^5 = 1 + 5 a_2 x^2 + 5 a_3 x^3 + 10 a_2x^4 + 5a_4 x^4...$

$\sin y = (1-1/6+1/120...) + (1-1/2+1/24...) a_2 x^2$

$\sin y = \sin 1 + (cos 1) a_2 x^2.. $

$y'' + \sin y = 0$

$2a_2 + \sin 1 + 6a_3 x + (12 a_4 + \cos 1 a_2) x^2 = 0$

$a_2 = (-1/2) (\sin 1), a_3 = 0, a_4 = (-1/12)(\cos 1)(-1/2)(\sin 1)$

$y = \sin 1 - (1/2) (\sin 1) x^2 + (1/48) (\sin 2) x^4$

Comment: Hi Doug, did you mean $y(0)=0$ on the second line?

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you may have problems identifying the first three "non-zero" terms. What if $a_0 = a_1=a_2=a_3=a_4=0$ ?

Comment: That should make it too much worse.  But if I had to find more than 3 it could have become quite difficult.

Comment: You would get a cleaner solution without needing to collect an infinite number of constant, linear etc. terms if you started with $\sin y=\sin(y-y_0)\cos(y_0)+\cos(y-y_0)\sin(y_0)$.